# How to make for loop to do all functions before next iteration in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, for-loop, asynchronous

everyone. I am doing an application that adds and updates fileds in database.
My problem is that my loop continues even though database updating calls still not yet successfully finished.
How can I manage to make for loop wait unit those functions finish before continuing the loop?

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is this piece of code:

```
for(i = 0; i < treatments.length; i++) {
    collection3.find({"_id": parseInt(treatments[i])}).toArray(function(err, results) {
    if(results[0].maxPrice < parseInt(treatmentsPrices[i])){
        collection3.update({"_id": parseInt(treatments[i])}, {"maxPrice": parseInt(treatmentsPrices[i])}, function(err, success) {
            counter++;
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
    if(results[0].minPrice > parseInt(treatmentsPrices[i])){
        collection3.update({"_id": parseInt(treatments[i])}, {"minPrice": parseInt(treatmentsPrices[i])}, function(err, success) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
    collection3.update({"_id": parseInt(treatments[i])}, {$addToSet: {"doctors": parseInt(doctorId)}}, function(err, success) {
        console.log(err);
    });
    collection3.update({"_id": parseInt(treatments[i])}, {$addToSet: {"hospitals": parseInt(hospitals[i])}}, function(err, success) {
        console.log(err);
    });
    if(newHospitalName != null) {
        collection3.update({"_id": parseInt(treatments[i])}, {$addToSet: {"hospitals": parseInt(hospitalId)}}, function(err, success) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
    });                         
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise using some library when you need to do asynchronous things.
I wrote a small example based in your code using [when](https://www.npmjs.com/package/when), you can see all methods [here](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/api.md#api)

```js
var when = require('when');
var promises = [];

var treatmentsUpdater = function (opts) {
  var treatments = opts.treatments;
  var treatmentsPrices = opts.treatmentsPrices;
  var doctorId = opts.doctorId
  var hospitals = opts.hospitals;
  var hospitalId = opts.hospitalId

  collection3.find({"_id": parseInt(treatments[i])}).toArray(function(err, results) {
    if(results[0].maxPrice < parseInt(treatmentsPrices[i])){
      collection3.update({"_id": parseInt(treatments[i])}, {"maxPrice": parseInt(treatmentsPrices[i])}, function(err, success) {
        counter++;
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
    if(results[0].minPrice > parseInt(treatmentsPrices[i])){
      collection3.update({"_id": parseInt(treatments[i])}, {"minPrice": parseInt(treatmentsPrices[i])}, function(err, success) {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
    collection3.update({"_id": parseInt(treatments[i])}, {$addToSet: {"doctors": parseInt(doctorId)}}, function(err, success) {
      console.log(err);
    });
    collection3.update({"_id": parseInt(treatments[i])}, {$addToSet: {"hospitals": parseInt(hospitals[i])}}, function(err, success) {
      console.log(err);
    });
    if(newHospitalName != null) {
      collection3.update({"_id": parseInt(treatments[i])}, {$addToSet: {"hospitals": parseInt(hospitalId)}}, function(err, success) {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
  });
}

for(i = 0; i < treatments.length; i++) {
  var opts = {
    treatments: treatments[i],
    treatmentsPrices: treatmentsPrices[i],
    doctorId: doctorId,
    hospitals: hospitals[i],
    hospitalId: hospitalId
  }
  promises.push(treatmentsUpdater(opts))   
}

when.all(promises).then(function () {
  console.log("The database has been updated")
})
```

You also can use native promises: [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Answer (score 1):

I will go and shamelessly advertise our own library called [Coastline](http://coastline.very.lv). The code would look something like this.

```js
CL.each(treatments, function* (treatment, i) {
  
  var results = yield collection3.find({"_id": parseInt(treatment)}).toArray(CL.cb());
  
  if (results[0].maxPrice < parseInt(treatmentsPrices[i])) {
    CL.bg(collection3.update({"_id": parseInt(treatment)}, {"maxPrice": parseInt(treatmentsPrices[i])}, CL.cb()));
  }
  if(results[0].minPrice > parseInt(treatmentsPrices[i])) {
    CL.bg(collection3.update({"_id": parseInt(treatment)}, {"minPrice": parseInt(treatmentsPrices[i])}, CL.cb()));
  }
                       
  CL.bg(collection3.update({"_id": parseInt(treatment)}, {$addToSet: {"doctors": parseInt(doctorId)}}, CL.cb()));
  
  CL.bg(collection3.update({"_id": parseInt(treatment)}, {$addToSet: {"doctors": parseInt(doctorId)}}, CL.cb()));
  
  CL.bg(collection3.update({"_id": parseInt(treatment)}, {$addToSet: {"hospitals": parseInt(hospitals[i])}}, CL.cb()));
  
  if(newHospitalName != null) {
    CL.bg(collection3.update({"_id": parseInt(treatment)}, {$addToSet: {"hospitals": parseInt(hospitalId)}}, CL.cb()));
  }
  
});
```

The library will wait for all `CL.bg()` calls to finish before running the next `CL.each()` iteration. You can replace `CL.bg()` with `yield` for everything to execute in sequence inside the iteration.

Comment: What is this ' * ' after function for? I got an Unexpected token error.

Comment: it's a generator function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function* which version of Node are you using?

Comment: Ok, I found it. I have to have 0.12 to use it and run it with a flag --harmony_generators. Am I right?